# Group by in MongoDB and get all matching documents with latest date of each group

Tags: mongodb

Below is the data that I have in my DB:

```
{ "School": "A",
  "Class": "A",
  "Student": "XXX",
  "Date": ISODate("2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "A",
  "Class": "B",
  "Student": "YYY",
  "Date": ISODate("2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "A",
  "Class": "C",
  "Student": "ZZZ",
  "Date": ISODate("2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "B",
  "Class": "A",
  "Student": "ABC",
  "Date": ISODate("2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "B",
  "Class": "B",
  "Student": "DEF",
  "Date": ISODate("2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "B",
  "Class": "C",
  "Student": "GHI",
  "Date": ISODate("2019-02-03T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

My objective is to get all the documents in each 'School' group with the latest  "Date" in each 'School' Group, not the latest "Date' of the whole DB.

Expected Result:

```
{ "School": "A",
  "Class": "A",
  "Student": "XXX",
  "Date": ISODate("2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "A",
  "Class": "C",
  "Student": "ZZZ",
  "Date": ISODate("2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{ "School": "B",
  "Class": "C",
  "Student": "GHI",
  "Date": ISODate("2019-02-03T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

I have tried using

```
db.myDB.aggregate([
  { "$sort": {
               "School":1, 
               "Date":1
             }
  },
  { "$group": {"_id": {School:"$School"},
                    "fullDocument": {
                         $push: 
                           {School: "$School", Class: "$Class", Date: $Date"}
                    }, 
                    "LatestDate": {"$max": "$Date"}
              }
  }
])
```

What I get in 'fullDocument' still includes all documents not with the latest 'Date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to group on the basis of School and get the entire document for a particular school in an array by using $ROOT

Then you just need to get the documents having Date as the max date in that array using filter

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$School",
      data: {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.Date",
              {
                $max: "$data.Date"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```